# RadioGroup issue

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

i'm trying to get the radiobutton text from the radiogroup but issue is: it didn't get the value. i searched on other links but didn't helpful for me.

```
    private EditText FirstName;
    private EditText LastName;
   private RadioGroup Gender;
    private EditText MobileNo;
  private RadioButton btn_gender;
    private Button BtnNext;
    private ProgressBar  progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_form);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        LastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        Gender=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

        MobileNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.btn_mobile);
        BtnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_regform);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


  int selectedId=Gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        btn_gender=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);



        BtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Firebase ref=new Firebase(config_firebaseurl.FIREBASE_URL);


                String fname=FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
                String lname=LastName.getText().toString().trim();
               String gender=btn_gender.getText().toString().trim();
                String phoneno=BtnNext.getText().toString().trim();

                registration_form reg=new registration_form();
                reg.setFirstName(fname);
                reg.setLastName(lname);
                reg.setGender(gender);
                reg.setmobileNo(phoneno);

                ref.child("registration_form").setValue(reg);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

and i'm getting this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: associate.aclass.associate1, PID: 28847
>                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                    at
>   associate.aclass.associate1.registration_form_handler$2.onClick(registration_form_handler.java:81)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

Comment: You have user setOnCheckedChangeListener what if there is no check changed ? Try to follow this tutorial it will help you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_radiogroup_control.htm

Comment: @RakshitNawani i also tried this way .. but getting same error.

Comment: Do this also  
int selectedId=Gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
btn_gender=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
and for fetching text do this btn_gender.getText();

Comment: @RakshitNawani tried but same error

Comment: Update your code in here so that we can see it

Comment: @RakshitNawani updated and same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btn_gender is null you need to do this outside of Gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener to initialize btn_gender

```
btn_gender = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonID); // use your id
```

Comment: Thanks mate. you made my day